# Node JS MYSQL query doesn't run, but no errors logged

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have the following code, which should update the url column of row 31 in the services table:

```
connection.getConnection(function(err, connection) {

   if (err) {
      console.log(err);
   } 
   const query = "update services set ? where ?;";
   const params = [{ url: "www.test.com" }, { id: 31 }];

   connection.query(query, params, function(error, rows, fields) {
      if (error) {
         console.log("failed");
      }
      console.log("success");
   });

   console.log(mysql.format(query, params));

   connection.release();
});
```

When I run it, the query doesn't get run, and the database remains unchanged. Only this is logged in the console:

```
update services set `url` = 'www.test.com' where `id` = 31;
```

This confuses me, as I would expect either 'success' or 'failed' to follow. So no errors are being thrown. The query also runs fine directly in the DB (if copied and pasted into workbench). If I replace the query with this:

```
   connection.query("select curdate();", function(error, rows, fields) {
```

then I get exactly what I expected in the console:

```
update services set `url` = 'www.test.com' where `id` = 31;
success
```

Can anybody explain what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

OK... problem was with my MYSQL DB.
I noticed after a minute of waiting there was a error being thrown: 'ER_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT', which set me looking at the DB. Running 'show open tables where in_use>0;' showed the tables were getting locked. The reason - somehow the autocommit setting has been changed. God knows how I managed that - maybe accidental click in my DB admin tool. Restored that setting to true, and everything works again.